# error: unable to locate wsdl at wsdl location, in Weblogic soap web-service(top-down approach) using OEPE

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, weblogic

I am working on **Weblogic soap web-service(top-down approach) using OEPE(oracle enterprise pack for eclipse)**. when I tried to generate a web-service from wsdl, I came across the error: **unable to locate wsdl at wsdl location**.

Irrespective of wsdl location in project, the wsdl location portion of web-serivce annotation is getting generated like this, I am trying to solve this from last three days please help me.

```
@WebService(portName = "mon_tySOAP", serviceName = "mon_ty", 
targetNamespace = "http://www.example.org/mon_ty/",wsdlLocation = "/wsdls/mon_ty.wsdl", 
endpointInterface = "org.example.mon_ty.MonTy")
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm having similar issues. It's obnoxious.

always with the /wsdls/ :(